# Binding multiple enums to a combobox in WPF

Tags: wpf, binding

In my project i want to make something, but really dont know if are possible...

I have one combobox, that depending on the condition , should change the enum. But i need to bind this to feed my model from view and dont know how i bind multiple enums to a combobox in WPF.

Someone knows if are possible ?

Already tried something like this example:

```
var myDataObject = (ConditionToFeedDataObjectEnum == 1 ? FirstEnum : SecondEnum);
Binding myBinding = new Binding("MyComboBox");
myBinding.Source = myDataObject;
MyComboBox.SetBinding((dont know what put here, tried ComboBox.propertys..), myBinding);
```

But with enums and combobox in wpf are diferent

Comment: Please provide more information on your (View-)Model or what you want to achieve in general.

Comment: Hello. Its a blank WPF view with only a combobox. And my model its like: public virtual Int32 Id {get;set;}, public virtual Int32 Value {get;set;}. Etc... Its a basic test i'm trying to do, using multiple bindings on a combobox with more than one enum